# Alternative of Html.Raw in ASP.NET WebForms

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I was getting error "A potential dangerous request" .. in Web Form application I have tried with "validatepage=false" and "" then i tried Server.HtmlEncode so it is saving encoded html in database.  Now when i showed the data in Repeater control by `Server.HtmlDecode(DataContent.FieldValue("Contents", Container))` It is showing text with html tags like `<p>asfd</p>`..

how i can resolve this issue? In razor view Html.Raw works fine but what is alternative in webform view / ASP.NET? Can anybody help?

Comment: I tried a lot but i resolve it myself :)  <%# HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Server.HtmlDecode(DataContent.FieldValue("ContentBody", Container)))%>

Comment: Yeah this worked for me in `<asp:Literal Mode="PassThrough" runat="server" ID="litError" runat="server" />`

Comment: @ImranRashid your solution works but Why did you use HtmlDecode twice ?

Answer (score 10):

you can use <%= value %> which will *not* encode the value.

or you can implement your own version of HTML.Raw

Html.Raw returns an IHtmlString instance which is almost same as string but ASP.net doesn't encode IHtmlString.

Simple function to replicate HTML.Raw()

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Stops asp.net from encoding the source HTML string.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IHtmlString HTMLRaw(string source)
    {
        return new HtmlString(source);
    }
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use asp:Literal with Mode=PassThrough

Comment: same result?   <asp:Literal Mode="PassThrough" runat="server" Text='<%# Server.HtmlDecode(DataContent.FieldValue("ContentBody", Container))%>'></asp:Literal>

Comment: asp:listeral with passthrough is what worked for me finally

Comment: passthrough for the win! `<asp:Literal Mode="PassThrough" runat="server" ID="litError" runat="server" />` with `this.litError.Text = "Example link  <a href=\"https://www.google.com" target=\"_blank\">Google Search</a>";`