# How to stop asp.net encoding characters before outputing to html?

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, encoding

I have a function that generates a javascript code for me.

```
<img src="abc.png" alt="hello" onclick="<%: getOnCilckJS(arg)  %>" />
```

c# code

```
protected String getOnCilckJS(int arg)
{
  if (arg==1)
  {
     return "alert('hello world');";
  }
  else
  {  return "alert('hello universe');"; 
  }
}
```

all works fine apart from when the page is loaded asp.net converts single quotations `'` to the encoded html string (`&#39;`)

How can I avoid this and make `'` appear in the html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code working to me :

> But just change <%: to <%= ( and I send the parameter myself)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="xxxx.aspx.cs" Inherits="SampleAngularApp.xxxx" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>          
        **<img src="abc.png" alt="hello" onclick="<%= getOnCilckJS(11)  %>" />**
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Server side

```
**protected string getOnCilckJS(int arg)**
        {
            if (arg == 1)
            {
                return "alert('hello world');";
            }
            else
            {
                return "alert('hello universe');";
            }
        }
```

I got the alert message without any single quote

Answer (score 1):

You're using `<%: %>`, which actually [does encode](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/06/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx) the value. You're looking for `<%= %>`.

See also [Diference between special tags asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154310/diference-between-special-tags-asp-net).

Answer (score 1):

Your application is Web Forms or MVC?

If it is MVC, you can try the Html.Raw(...) function, If it is Web Forms you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819655/alternative-of-html-raw-in-asp-net-webforms).

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET WebForms the razor syntax is invalid so the way to stop the string encoding in the output of a string is to use the `HtmlString()` for example the inline syntax is:

```
<%: new HtmlString(stringVariable) %>
```

Below is an example how to output a variable in JavaScript inline code on a ASP.NET WebForm page. The code sample outputs a C# string array into a JavaScript array:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var array = ["<%: new HtmlString(string.Join(@""",""", stringArray)) %>"];
</script>
```

Normally, the double quote characters are html encoded and converted as `&quot;` and breaks the JavaScript syntax - using the `HtmlString()` method stops the encoding.

However, as stated in previous answer to avoid using the HtmlString() simply use the appropriate special ASP.Net tag syntax to output your values - `<%: %>` encodes characters and `<%= %>` is raw output!

[Review the differences between ASP.Net special tags here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18154310/diference-between-special-tags-asp-net)!

Comment: I prefer this method (except for your *however* statement) using `<%: %>` everywhere and then use `<%: new HtmlString(...)%>` where appropriate, at least in `WebForms` which our site is still in.