# c# html in database shows up in web page

Tags: c#, mysql

I have html in my data in MySql but when I retrieve the data in c# GridView it shows up. This does not happen when I pull the data in a classic asp page. How do I get rid of the HTML such as hyperlink and mailto markup but still retain the hyperlinks and mailto format in the asp.net c# web page. When I show the gridview all the markup is there instead of the actual hyperlink or mailto or even the paragraph formatting.

Comment: if you can possibly get rid of the html out of your real data that's what I would concentrate on.  the alternative is using regular expressions and i would not want to go there...

Comment: Default behavior of ASP.NET is to HTML-encode anything you output to a web page. You have to explicitly tell it not to if you want the HTML actually rendered. Something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445196/how-to-stop-asp-net-encoding-characters-before-outputing-to-html

Comment: Show us a minimal code example

Comment: Thanks all for your comments Tieson T. helped to solve the issue and I can now use my HTML formatting in MYSQL and it renders correctly. Thanks all